# How can I use a line number to copy a line to where my cursor is?

Tags: cursor-movement

A lot of times I'm in a situation similar to this:

```
1. <Line 1>
2. <Line 2>
3. <Line 3>
4. <Cursor is here>
5. <I want to copy line 1 here>
```

An easy solution is `` mm:1<CR>yy`mp `` - that is, make a mark at line 4, go to line 1, copy it, go back to the mark, and paste.

Is there a shorter/more fluid solution to this? I do this often enough that I'm happy to make a mapping for it.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Looks like a case for ex copy (`:help :co` or `:help :t`):

```
:1t4
```

or, using your cursor's position:

```
:1t.
```

This does not copy the line to the yank register, which might or might not be what you want.

Comment: I do not use ex copy enough, good suggestion.

Answer (score 11):

You could shorten it by not using marks and yank the line directly.

```
:1y<CR>p
```

Command version of yank takes a `{range}` so select a line or a group of lines.

Additionally, the range value can be either absolute or relative. Lines above the cursor are negative distance and below are positive. So yanking two lines above is `:-2y` and yanking two lines below is `:+2y`.