# How to yank a line with a certain line number?

Tags: cut-copy-paste

Say that I am on line 20 and I would like to yank line 4, how can I do that?

And similarly, how can I yank a line relative to my cursor position, say the one 3 lines up?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I use a line number to copy a line to where my cursor is?](http://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/3055/how-can-i-use-a-line-number-to-copy-a-line-to-where-my-cursor-is)

Answer (score 71, accepted):

From [`:help :yank`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/change.txt.html#E850):

```
:[range]y[ank] [x]      Yank `[range]` lines [into register x].
```

So, to yank line 4, one would type:

```
:4yank
```

Note you can easily do this from insert mode with `<C-o>`; this allows you to
execute one command, after which you're returned to insert mode; for example:

```
<C-o>:4yank
```

You can, of course, also use other ranges. Some examples:

- Lines 1 to 3: `:1,3yank`
- The entire buffer: `:%yank`
- From the current line to the end of the buffer: `:.,$:yank`
- The current line and the next 3: `:.,+3yank`
- The current line and the previous 3: `:-3,.yank`
- The line 3 lines above the current line: `:-3yank`

The most useful things to remember about ranges:

- It's in the form of `:line1,line2command`.
- A `.` is the current line (you can actually omit the dot in most cases; `:.,+3yank` and `:,+3yank` are the same)
- You specify lines relative to the current position with `+n` and `-n`.

By default the lines will be yanked into the default register (`""`). If you want to use a named register, add a space an then the name of the register (naked, not prefixed with a double quote), eg:

```
:30,30yank a
> 10 lines yanked into "a
```

See [`:help [range]`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/cmdline.txt.html#E16) for more
information.

Comment: Bonus points for mentioning <C-o>, I'm underusing that.

Comment: It's also worth mentioning that you can abbreviate `:4yank` with `:4y`

Answer (score 43):

In addition to Carpetsmoker's answer, I should point out the awesome `:help :m` and `:help :t`.

The canonical behavior of `:<range>t<address>` and `:<range>m<address>` is to copy/move the lines in `<range>` **below** the given `<address>`.

If you want to copy line 4 **right below** the current line you can do this:

```
:4t.
```

where…

- `4` is the line you want to copy,
- `.` is the current line.

See `:help :range`.

If you want to copy line 4 **right above** the current line, you can do this:

```
:4t-
```

where…

- `4` is still the line to copy,
- `-` is the line *above* the current line.

Answer (score 3):

Simply type

```
:4y
```

to yank line 4

it will go into the unnamed register. Then, (for example) you can use `p` to put it elsewhere. You can also use `[n]p`, e.g. 10p to paste it 10 times.

You can put it into a named register such as "a" with

```
:4y a
```

Comment: The part about putting it into a named register with "ay4 doesn't look right.  If you do that, vim will be waiting for you to say "4 whats?".  E.g. if you then hit Enter it will yank 4 lines starting at the current position, if you type /foo<Enter> it will yank til the 4th following occurrance of "foo", etc.

Comment: The last command should read `4G"ayy`.

Answer (score 1):

Besides the ex-mode commands that you've got you can achieve that also it in command mode, e.g. by: `4GY''` - which means: goto line 4 (`4G`), yank line (`Y`), and return to previous line (`''`).

You can also use jump marks; for your second question, e.g. by: `mm3kY'm` - which means: set mark m (`mm`), go three lines up (`3k`), yank line (`Y`), return to mark m (`'m`).

Comment: Using `` is probably a better recommendation than '' since the former goes back to the same line and column.  Ditto for `m vs. 'm.

Comment: I agree. (Any idea how to create literal backtics in wiki markup since they have a special meaning?) - Otherwise your comment will serve well as amendment to my answer and as hint for the readers.

Comment: You have to use multiple backticks to delimit the inline code (c.f., http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#code).  I know it works in questions/answers, but I couldn't get it to work in my comment.

Answer (score 1):

You can do

```
:10y <Enter> (to copy the line 10)
p (paste line 10 where the cursor is)
```

Setting up relative number helps in moving between lines of code as well.

```
:set relativenumber
```

Now you can copy the 5th line above the cursor with:

```
:-5y <Enter>
:p (to paste)
```