# Deleting a range of n lines before and after a matched line?

Tags: regular-expression

I have a repetitive configuration file and I'd like to match a regex and delete a range of lines before, and after a match.  I'd also like delete the match in one command.

I can use...

`:g/match/-1d`

...several times to delete more than one line from before a match...

...and combine it with a few calls to...

`:g/match/+1d`

...to delete more than one line after the match...

But is there any way to delete a range of lines, before, after and including, the match with one command?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You're almost there; you can also specify a range of lines, which is in the form of `[line1],[line2][command]`, instead of just `[line][command]` (like you're using now).

You can use `.` to refer to the current line.

- For the current & next line: `:g/match/.,+1d`
- For the current & previous line: `:g/match/-1,.d`
- For the previous, current, and next line: `:g/match/-1,+1d`

See [`:help [range]`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/cmdline.txt.html#E16) for more information, and [in this answer there are a few more examples](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/3232/51).

Comment: Is the syntax the same in sed?

Comment: @leeand00 No. All that `:g` does is run an ex command on the lines that match a pattern. So typing `:g/match/.,+1d` would be exactly the same as going to all lines with `match`, and typing `:.,+1d`

Comment: This is the coolest thing I've learned on vim in a while.  Thanks for sharing!