# Search for a pattern, copy the line with the matching pattern, copy the next 2 lines, output the results into a new file

Tags: search, command

I have a file with data that goes like this.

```
Engine1
Temp:10
Humidity:23 
Engine1
Temp:13
Humidity:21 
Engine2
Temp:10
Humidity:23
```

This pattern repeats throughout the file.
I want to do the following in a single vim command.

1. Search for `Engine1`
2. Copy the line that has the pattern `Engine1`
3. Copy the next 2 lines (which has the data related to it)
4. Output the results to a new file

This command needs to do this for the whole file wherever this pattern appears.

Comment: You can use `let @c=''|:g/engine1/1,3y C` then in the new file `"cP` will paste the match. [regular expression deletion](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/3411/deleting-a-range-of-n-lines-before-and-after-a-matched-line) will help. Depending on what you mean by file `:h :redir` may assist

Comment: This is the command I was looking for :g/Engine1/.,.+2w! >> Newfile.txt

Answer (score 2):

## EDITED:

You can use this:

```
:g/Engine1/.,.+2w! >> Newfile.txt
```

It will find all the occurence of Engine1 and copy his line with the two line below to the file `Newfile.txt`

You can also create a personnal command:

```
:command -nargs=1 MySearch :g/<args>/.,.+2w! >> file.txt
```

After entering this command, if you try writting `:MySearch Engine1` It will do the same things but you can change your key (Engine2, Engine3, etc.)

## More details

- `:g` means `global` find all the lines conaining a pattern and execut a command for each of them `:global/pattern/command` (see `:help :global`)
- `:w` means `write` write the content of the actual buffer to a file - `:write file`(see `:help :write`)
- `:command` create a user-custom command (see `:help command`)

Comment: I think you would want to *append* rather than *overwrite* to the file. so you should probably use `:g.../.,.+2w >> newfile.txt`

Comment: Good Idea!  It  can help this way. I will edit my answer.

Comment: Note that `:g` abbreviates `:global` and `:w!` abbreviates `:write!` (I find myself among a minority that prefers longhand in scripts and answers; shorthands are reserved for interactive use)

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt That worked!

Comment: @FabriceHategekimana Thank you so much! Could you please explain the significance of the .,. (dot comma dot) before +2w?

Comment: The this is the description of a range (e.g. [3,4] will be written as `3,4`). It indicate wich range you want. The dot is a special symbol, it mean the actual line (so `.,.+2` = [actual line, actual line + 2])

Comment: D.Ben Knoble, you are right. I usually use the short notation when I'am customizing my projects on the fly and I prefer the long notation in my .vimrc. For an answer, I think the short version is less frightening but it's true I should give some explanations. I will edit my answer

Comment: Note that you don't actually need the dots at all... `:g/Engine1/,+2w >>file.txt` works just as well. You don't need `:w!` either, just `:w` will do since you're appending.

Comment: Okay, I will make a change