# Yank current line range

Tags: cut-copy-paste, line-numbers, range

I would like to yank the current selected line range (not the line range *content*).

For example, if my selection goes from line 51 to 67, I looking for a way to yank `51,67` to my default register.

Comment: Does https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/3231/10604 answer your question?

Comment: sorry my question was not clear: I don't want to yank the line content but the line number

Comment: With the edit, this should stay open.

Comment: What do you want to do with that register?

Comment: Do you still have something open in your question? How can we help you further? Otherwise maybe could you accept one of the answers using the v button next to the arrow voting buttons? It allow the question to rest :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to copy the range specification you could add the following mapping:

```
vnoremap <silent><C-s> :call setreg('"', line("'<") .. ',' .. line("'>"))<cr>
```

In Visual mode is you hit <kbd>Ctrl s</kbd> the range specification will be copy in the `"` register.

e.g. if you select lines 51 to 67 and hit <kbd>Ctrl s</kbd> the `"` register will contain the string `51,67`.

Alternatively you could do it using a `range` function:

```
function! CopyRange() range
    call setreg('"', a:firstline .. ',' .. a:lastline)
endfunction

vnoremap <silent><C-s> :call CopyRange()<cr>
```

Or if you want to stay in Visual mode taking advantage of the `<cmd>` qualifier you can do (Thanks to @ChristianBrabandt):

```
vnoremap <C-s> <cmd>call setreg('"', line("v") .. ',' .. line("."))<cr>
```

More information with [:help line()](https://vimhelp.org/builtin.txt.html#line%28%29).

Comment: I'm a bit confused by  the `'[` and `']` marks. According to `:help '[` they are the first and last characters of inserted text. I would have expected `'<` and `'>` for visual selection instead. Sorry for the constant second-guessing.

Comment: @Friedrich, thanks for your second guessing :-) I was too fast. You were of course right with `'<` and `'>` but also the `<cmd>`  makes that the marks were not set, only the second attempt was succesfull. I was too fast in my tests :-| This version is more carefully tested. Thanks again :-)

Comment: `'<` and `'>` are only updated once visual mode has ended (which is not the case for `<cmd>` and `<scriptcmd>`. In visual mode you can use `line('v')` and `line('.')` instead

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt Thanks I didn't new the `v` position.

Comment: Sorry for the late comment and thank you so much for this code snippet! I had issue making `setreg()` work until I removed the following line to my vim configuration: `set clipboard=unnamed`. Do you have any idea why `setreg()` doesn't work with this configuration ?

Comment: If you set `clipboard` to `unnamed` your default (the one to past and to copy) register is `*`. You can replace in the code `setteg('"'` by `setreg('*'` and keep your `set clipboard=unnamed`

Comment: Indeed thank you so much! Shall I edit my question to update this specific detail ?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. You could adapt your question and I'll update my answer then :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you hit `y` it will goes into the default register `"`.

If you want it to go to the system clipboard (`+` for Linux, `*` for Windows) you have to specify the register (`"+y` for Linux, `"*y` for Windows).

If you set the `clipboard` option to `unnamedplus`:

```
:set clipboard=unnamedplus
```

then by default the Vim will use the `+` register to yank (copy) and paste.

If you set the `clipboard` option to `unnamed`:

```
:set clipboard=unnamed
```

then by default the Vim will use the `*` register to yank (copy) and paste.

In such case you can just hit `y` to yank to the system clipboard.

Comment: You might also include the range syntax `:51,67yank`

Comment: *"`+` for Linux, `*` for Windows"* - yes, but only half the truth. See `:help quote+`. Btw, there's a really nice and short article on [X selections](https://www.jwz.org/doc/x-cut-and-paste.html) by jwz. You only have to stop reading when he goes into Emacs specifics.

Comment: I don't want to yank the line range content but the line range itself (`51,67` in my example)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback :-) I'm too much in Vim, when I read `51,67` my brain translate it into the content of the lines from 51 to 67 ;-)